# SuiteScript 2.0 Invalid Commit On Workorder Save

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm attempting to load a workorder, iterate the sublist of items, check to see if the commitinventory field is a value of 3 and, if so, change it to a value of 1. When I try to save the workorder, I get error: INVALID_COMMIT_OPTION_ON_LINE_1. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// SuiteScript:     2.1
// SCRIPT ID:       
// CREATE DATE:     3/27/2023
// Author:

/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/record', 'N/log'],
    /**
     * @param {record} record
     * @param {log} log
     */
    function (record, log) {

        function post(context) {
            let wo = record.load({
              type: 'workorder',
              id: 52178865
            });
            
            if(wo) {
                let count = wo.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'});
                
                for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    let com = wo.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'commitinventory',
                        line: i
                    });
                    if(com == 3) {
                        wo.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: 'commitinventory',
                            line: i,
                            value: '1'
                        });
                    }                  
                }
                wo.save();
            } else {
              log.debug('Error', 'No WO');
            }      
        }
        return {
            post: post
        };
    });
```

I used some debugging to make sure that I'm getting the correct initial values of those fields, and then did another loop of debugging to see that those fields were correctly set. For the setSublistValue call, I tried using a string and an int and got the same error.

Comment: is it possible to do it thru the web interface? I mean, open the WO page and try to enter 1 into the column. This is the first place to start